# Should outdoor lamp post be on GFCI

Tags: gfci

I have an outdoor lamppost at the end of my driveway. Its not currently on a GFCI circuit. Shouldn't it be? It does not have an outlet by it. If it did, then it would need GFCI for sure, right?

Answer (score 3):

If a lamppost circuit is installed at least 18" below grade then the lamppost and the circuit does not need to be GFCI protected. If you install a new receptacle to the existing lamppost the the receptacle must be GFCI protected. In fact reference NEC Table 300.5 column 4.